# Обновление свойства через event, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**Не получается обновить свойство в ViewModel и соответственно View через событие**

Есть класс в котором генерируется событие:

```
public class StringGenerator
{
    public  event Action<string> StringEvent;

    // Функционал активирующий StringEvent
}
```

Есть класс который подписан на это событие  и два свойства типа `string` и `ObservableCollection<string>`, которые обновляются этим событием (см конструктор):

```
public class StringProvider : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _stringCollection;
    private string _textMessage;
    private StringGenerator _stringGenerator;

    public ObservableCollection<string> StringCollection
    {
        get { return _stringCollection; }
        set
        {
            _stringCollection = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StringCollection));
        }
    }

    public string TextMessage
    {
        get { return _textMessage; }
        set
        {
            _textMessage = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextMessage));
        }
    }

    public StringProvider()
    {
        TextMessage = "XXXXXXX";
        StringCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        _stringGenerator = new StringGenerator();

        // Подписка на StringEvent
        _stringGenerator.StringEvent += param =>
        {
            TextMessage = param;
            StringCollection.Add(param);
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Есть промежуточный класс для реализации MVVM:

```
public interface IDataService
{
    StringProvider StringProviderLocal { get; set; }
}

public class DataService:IDataService
{
    private StringProvider _stringProviderLocal;

    public StringProvider StringProviderLocal
    {
        get { return _stringProviderLocal; }
        set { _stringProviderLocal = value; }
    }

    public DataService()
    {
        _stringProviderLocal = new StringProvider();
    }
}
```

Есть ViewModel в которой есть экземпляр `DataService` и свойства типа `string` и `ObservableCollection<string>` которые по задумке должны обновляться при срабатывании `StringEvent`.

```
public class ViewModelLocal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DataService _dataService;

    public ObservableCollection<string> StringCollection
    {
        get { return _dataService.StringProviderLocal.StringCollection; }
        set
        {
            _dataService.StringProviderLocal.StringCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StringCollection));
        }
    }
    public string TextMessage
    {
        get { return _dataService.StringProviderLocal.TextMessage; }
        set
        {
            _dataService.StringProviderLocal.TextMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextMessage));
        }
    }

    public ViewModelLocal()
    {
        _dataService = new DataService();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Есть View где реализуется `Binding`:

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding StringCollection}"/>
<TextBlock Text = "{Binding TextMessage}" />
```

При запуске приложения TextBlock Text содержит "XXXXXXX". Все как и должно быть.

Однако, после срабатывания события `StringEvent` обновление `ObservableCollection<string> StringCollection` происходит в вот обновление `string TextMessage` нет.

Любые попытки изменить значение `TextMessage` внутри класса `StringProvider`:

```
TextMessage = "UUUUUUU";
```

не приводят к изменению данных во View

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: коментарий удален ;)

Answer (score 1):

Обновление коллекции происходит не потому, что вы написали там `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StringCollection))`, а потому что коллекция реализует интерфейс `INotifyCollectionChanged`, т.е. она выдаёт уведомление об изменении при добавлении / замене / удалении элементов внутри коллекции. 
Вы можете убирать `OnPropertyChanged` из сеттера коллекции, т.к. он отработает только в том случае, если вы сделаете `StringCollection = new ObservableCollection`.

Попробуйте убрать класс `DataService` и напрямую взаимодействовать с элементами, вызывая обновления из вью-модели. В той части кода, которую вы показали, можно обойтись и без него. Вы только дублируете один и тот же код несколько раз

Comment: К сожалению убрать промежуточный класс нельзя так как в реале это приложение работает с несколькими поставщиками данных и DataService реализовывает интерфейс IDataSetrvice <T> где Т может быть различным источником данных через интерфейс IDataProvider

Comment: используйте интерфейсы и абстрактные классы. можно использовать IDataService<T> в качестве базового интерфейса, и от него уже создавать конкретные реализации типа IStreamDataProvider, IFileDataProvider. Возможно, поможет ковариантность обобщённых интерфейсов [ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.27.php)

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вы предоставляете обёртку к `StringProviderLocal.TextMessage`, вы должны извещать пользователей вашей `ViewModelLocal` о том, что это свойство поменялось. Для этого вы должны подписаться на `StringProviderLocal.PropertyChanged`, и при приходе события отправлять собственное событие.

(Вариант с пробросом подписки внутрь `StringProviderLocal` выглядит намного хуже, и прибавляет ненужной связности между моделью и клиентами VM.)

---

Да, это всё будет работать лишь если никто не меняет `_dataService.StringProviderLocal`. У вас нет возможности выяснить, менялся ли `StringProvider`, и обновить подписку, т. к. `DataService` не реализует INPC.